# Is it possible to add info or help text to an iPhone settings bundle?

Tags: iphone, settings, plist, settings.bundle

Several of the Apple-provided apps have informational/help text in their settings. For example, the Keyboard settings screen includes, under the *“.” shortcut* toggle, the help text "Double tapping the space bar will...".

I know I can do this in my app by adding a group footer, but is it possible to do this in the settings app by adding a field to the plist file in my Settings.bundle?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to recently changed Apple document, a FooterText key is available in PSGroupSpecifier dictionary, which is only available in iOS 4.0 or later.

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSGroupSpecifier.html

Answer (score 4):

The way I do it, and the way I have seen other third parties apps do it is just to use an informative Title as a PSGroupSpecifier

I have only seen the native Apple apps do it in this other, slightly nicer way. I expect the ability is buried deep in the undocumented regions of the SDK.

Answer (score 4):

Using FooterText key in PSGroupSpecifier is what you need to use. And it is documented as *xesique* already said.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the "FooterText" key is not built into the pop-up menu of the Settings Scheme / plist editor that is part of Xcode. When you select a "Group" and type a keyboard return or press the plus icon you are presented with a choice of either "New item"," "Type" of "Title". You are required to manually edit this key value. Then the text that you enter as the associated string will appear as grey text (rather than the black text used for the Groups members) and which maintains its upper / lowercase.